# Specify object value with vuex v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm coordinating input elements with the keys of an object on Vuex state. Let's say I've got this object:

```
myObj: { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

And a computed property in a component:

```
myObjVals: {
  get(){ return this.$store.state.myObj },
  set(//?) { //? },
},
```

In the template, I can get values *from* the store:

```
<input type="number" v-model="myObjVals['foo']"/>  // displays "1"
<input type="number" v-model="myObjVals['bar']"/>  // displays "2"
```

But when I adjust the value on an input, I get the error: "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

One obvious solution here is to have a different computed property for *each* key in `myObj`... but for larger objects, this gets repetitious/cumbersome. I am wondering if there is any way to code this as I am attempting to above, that is, using only one computed property to reference the object for both `get` and `set` functions in `v-model`.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, because VueJS has no way of knowing that it should use the setter of the object instead of directly altering the object it has gotten from the state. One way could be to use the `mapState` of Vuex to help generate the needed getters (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper). Edit: of course you could also use the non-strict mode of vuex

Comment: Aha - this is a sort of pass-by-reference error, isn't is?

Comment: Will check out `mapState`, thanks.

Comment: Yeah. You are getting the whole object and by accessing the different properties inside your model you are altering the object without using the setter. At least i believe that this is the case. Have you tried using the setter and calling a Vuex mutation for the object from there?

Comment: Oh - actually, that is a question. How would you code the setter in this case? For example, `set(key, value){ // commit with key & value payload }` ? The setter can receive the input value, but I'm not sure how to specify the key.

Comment: That was were i am unsure of. Is the setter even called if you do the computed property on the *whole* object and then change property values inside the `v-model`. I would assume that the settter isn't even called. And i also believe that you cannot write a custom setter based on key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Come to think of your problem once more. One solution could be something suggested here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

```
<input type="number" :value="myObjVals['foo']" @input="changeMyObj('foo', $event)"/>  // displays "1"
<input type="number" :value="myObjVals['bar']" @input="changeMyObj('bar', $event)"/>  // displays "2"
```

with computed property and a method:

```
computed: {
    myObjVals: function () {
        return this.$store.state.myObj
    }
},
methods: {
    changeMyObj(key, evt) {
        this.$store.commit('changeMyObj', {key: key, value: evt.data})
    }
}
```

With a mutation inside the store:

```
mutations: {
  changeMyObj(state, objInput) {
    state.myObj[objInput.key] = objInput.value
  }
}
```

Here is a "working" fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfab6tzp/346/

Not sure if this is the best solution possible, but it seems to be working

Comment: Awesome, working, thanks! I'm noticing in your fiddle you have two versions: `@input="changeMyObj('foo', $event)">` and `@input="(value) => { changeMyObj('bar', value) }"` ... in your opinion is one to be preferred?

Comment: Oh. I don't believe that the inline function is working properly. But i would assume that the other version (with a direct function call) is preferable since it does not generate multiple anonymous functions.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah I have the first plugged in and it does work. Thx!